# write to ostream inside of function with c++

Tags: c++

consider the following function:

```
void writer(ofstream &output) {
output << "a string to write" << endl;

}
```

but when i try to call this, i get an error that '<<' is not defined. how can I fix this?

Comment: Are you `using namespace std`?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your error.  Could you post some more of your code?

Comment: Are you compiling as a C program or C++?

Comment: @Thomas: Is `ofstream` available in C? Can you use references and operator overloading in C? Because the OP's three line snippet clearly uses all three.

Comment: @DeadMG:  A popular mistake is to compile C++ programs using a C compiler, e.g. `gcc` instead of `g++`.  The C language does not support left shifting of test pointers, so an error would be generated.

Comment: Please don't make us guess what the exact text of the error is.  Tell us!  It's OK to copy/paste the whole error into your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `#include <fstream>` or change `ofstream` to `ostream`

Most likely you lack an include, so that ofstream is only forward declared.